# wordpress: remove broken links to attachments

Tags: wordpress

Take a look at the following URL: `http:// www.samuel-berthelot.com / ? attachment_id=703`

There is a link to the next image that reads `lumière sur la marié`at the bottom of the image. It redirects to attachment with id 704.

I have set a permanent redirection to attachment with id 1743 because they were both showing the same image that I had uploaded twice at different points in time.

So it works fine, except that I would like to change the link to open the attachment with id 1743. This way I wouldn't have a 404 warning in Google Webmaster Tools.

How can I do that with Wordpress ? I don't know how this links are generated.

Comment: so you want to set another image at  attachment with id 1743 link?

Comment: If you go to phpmyadmin, you select wordpress database, then "suffix"_posts table, you can change manually the id of your attachments. Is that what you want? Maybe that's the answer.

Comment: What I mean is that the link should redirect to the new attachment, even though I set up a 301. This would be cleaner.  So I can change that directly in the database ? What would be the query ? I doubt it is in the _posts table, is it ?

Comment: I'll write you an aswer.

Comment: No wait, there's something that I don't understand. Why are you having 404 errors? If you have a working 301 redirection webmaster tools shouldn't tell you anything about 404.

Comment: It does... Somehow in the broken links section, it tells me that this link is broken. Yet the 301 is definitely in place because if I click on the link it redirects me to the other attachment. I'm starting to wonder if this Google webmaster tools is reliable..

Comment: If I click on the attachment 1743, I don't get redirected. I just got 200 server response and in fact I'm still on 1743 media attachment page.

Comment: yes, but if you browse to 704, you get redirected to 1743.

Comment: Ok, it works. When did you implement the 301 redirection? When is the last 404 error warning about that page (attachment 704)? Also, remove the attachment 704 link from your sitemap.

Comment: attachments are not on the sitemap. I've implemented the 301 before the 404 actually appeared in the errors of GWT.